# Incrustar botón en imágenes de un Slider

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tengo la tarea de hacer pequeñas modificaciones a una WEB y una de ellas es crear un Slider de 3 imágenes.

Mi problema está en que debo añadir un botón (que diga "Mas Información") por cada imagen, ese botón debe estar en diferentes posiciones en la imagen que le corresponde.

Aquí podrán ver el Slider en acción, pero me falta el incrustar los botones a cada imagen: https://desausrf.azurewebsites.net/

Este es mi codigo HTML

```
<section class="banners">
<div id="c-slider-banner">
                <div id="slider-banner">
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-3.png" alt="">
                        
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-2.png" alt="">
                        
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-1.png" alt="">                        
                    </section>

                </div>

            </div>
</section>
```

Este es el codigo CSS

```
#c-slider-banner {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 900px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
#slider-banner {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 300%;
    animation: cambio 20s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
#slider-banner section {
        width: 100%
    }
#slider-banner img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
@keyframes cambio{
    0% {margin-left: 0%}
    30% {margin-left: 0%}
    
    35% {margin-left: -100%}
    65% {margin-left: -100%}
    
    70% {margin-left: -200%}
    100% {margin-left: -200%}
}
.banners {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237,237,237,1) 0%, rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

---

mas o menos ya pude incrustar el botón, de la siguiente forma:

```
<div id="c-slider-banner">
                <div id="slider-banner">
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-2.png" alt="">
                        <div class="btn-float-card" style="bottom: 35%; left: -33%;">
                            <a class="btn btn-blue" style="border:none; background-color: #ea3c00;" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contacto">Mas información</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-3.png" alt="">
                        <div class="btn-float-card" style="bottom: 30%; left: -37%;">
                            <a class="btn btn-blue" style="border:none; background-color: #6380ba" asp-controller="Autodesk" asp-action="Autocad">Mas información</a>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-4.png" alt="">
                        <div class="btn-float-card" style="bottom: 23%; left: 7%;">
                            <a class="btn btn-blue" style="border:none; background-color: #614386" asp-controller="Adobe" asp-action="CreativeCloud">Mas información</a>
                        </div>                            
                    </section>
                    <section>
                        <img src="~/images/slider-banner-1.png" alt="">
                    </section>

                </div>

            </div>
```

pero ahora tengo otro problema, que cuando se re-dimensiona (resize) el explorador los botones se salen del lugar, Alguna idea de como podría proceder.

Comment: y en qué posiciones deben estar esos botones dentro del slide?

Comment: Hola, mas o menos en la segunda imagen el botón debería ir del centro a la derecha y en la tercera imagen del centro a la izquierda. He estado probando de muchas formas pero el botón siempre me aparece por debajo de la imagen y no montado en este.